# How to load Q library with Require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, q

My library use [kriskowal/Q promises library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and now I'm trying to load (with requirejs) application that use my library so I put all paths and shims and my `requirejs.config` section looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './',
    catchError: false,
    paths: {
        beril: '../engine/build/src/bundle',
        lodash: 'bower_components/lodash/lodash',
        three: 'bower_components/three.js/build/three',
        q: 'bower_components/q/q',

    },
    shim: {
        lodash: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        three: {
            exports: 'THREE'
        },
        q: {
            exports: 'Q'
        },
        beril: {
            deps: ['lodash', 'three', 'q'],
            exports: 'beril'
        },
    }
});
```

After this I suppose variables THREE, _ and Q to be defined in global space.
Now I'm loading and runinng application with this simple line:

```
require(['beril', 'js/stepbystep/' + $stateParams.page + '/app'], (beril, app) => app());
```

but then I'm getting error: `ReferenceError: Q is not defined` even though I can see in Chrome's network inspector that Q library have been loaded.

[image]

Also all the rest dependencies (THREE and _) are defined. Seems like requirejs`s shim does not work for this library. Can it be or am I missing something?

So what am I'm doing wrong and how should I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and it was to add `init` function to my library's shim and then add `Q` as global object manually so my shim section now looks like this:

```
shim: {
    lodash: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    three: {
        exports: 'THREE'
    },
    q: {
        exports: 'Q'
    },
    beril: {
        deps: ['lodash', 'three', 'q'],
        exports: 'beril',
        init: function(lodash, three, q){
            window.Q = q;
        }
    },
}
```

however I don't clearly understand why it does not work without this and are there better ways to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your configuration. For one thing, you have unnecessary `shim` configurations. I installed lodash just now (with `bower install lodash`) and searched its code. It calls `define`. So you **must not** set a `shim` for it. RequireJS won't give you an error but you will get undefined behavior. The same is true of Q: it calls `define` so, no `shim` for it. [Last I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30361895/1906307), `THREE` needs a `shim`.

The fact that Q calls `define` is also why it does not leak the symbol `Q` into the global space. It acts like a well-behaved AMD-module.

Ok, so how can we get Beril to find Q? [Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35164038/1906307) works but I find it slightly iffy. The problem is that `init` is executed *after* the shimmed module is loaded. As long as Beril refers to `Q` only in the body of functions to be executed later, it will work. And I guess this is how Beril works now. However, if a new version of Beril needs to refer to `Q` when the file that contains Beril is *first executed*, it will fail because `Q` does not exist yet.

One way to work around the problem that is future-proof is to use `map` and some glue. Keep your `shim` for `beril` but remove the `init`. Define a module named `q-glue`:

```
define(['q'], function (Q) {
    window.Q = Q;
    return Q;
});
```

And declare this [`map`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map) in your configuration:

```
map: {
    beril: {
        q: "q-glue"
    }
}
```

This says "when `q` is requested from `beril` load `q-glue` instead." By doing this, `window.Q` will be defined *before* Beril is loaded.

I take it you are the author of Beril. I urge you to make your library AMD-compatible so as to spare users of your library having to go through configuration pains to get it working with AMD-loaders (like RequireJS).

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me after I downgraded to version 0.9 up until 1.0.1 as mentioned in the readme. The current version 2.0.2 has significant braking changes as mentioned by Kris Kowal [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

I didn't have the need to set the global variable as the older version checks the environment and does so if loaded before require.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add `q` to `require()`...

```
require(['beril', 'q', 'js/stepbystep/' + $stateParams.page + '/app'], (app, beril, q) => app());
```

Comment: Is the path to `q` correct? If you view the console can you see the `q` library loading?

Comment: yes, as I notices in OP i can see it loaded as well as all other dependencies

Comment: also why I should load from `require`, shouldn't it be loaded from dependencies?