# ERROR ReferenceError: Q is not defined in Angular 11 project

Tags: angular, q, angular11

I have added a custom javascript file in my Angular 11 project (myCustomJS.js) that utilizes Q library.

However, I am getting "ERROR ReferenceError: Q is not defined" at below line of code in my javascript file.

**Error**: "ERROR ReferenceError: Q is not defined"

**On Line**: var deferred = Q.defer();

FYI, I have added following packages in package.config:

```
{
    "@types/q": "^1.5.4",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
}
```

I have added following in angular.json file:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/q/q.js",  // Added reference to Q Library
    "src/assets/js/myCustomJS.js"   // My Custom Javascript File
]
```

Added following types in tsconfig.app.json file:

```
"types": [
    "jquery",
    "q" // Added q type definitions
]
```

Not sure if I am missing any more reference(s) in my Angular 11 project. Please suggest how to fix Q is not defined error.

Comment: You are probably lacking importing it in your app.module.ts or in whatever module you want to use it

Comment: I added "import * as Q from 'q';" and added Q in imports array in app.module.ts but that leads to different compilation errors... such as: TS2322: Type 'typeof Q' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve “Q not defined” issue by commenting 2 lines (Line# 46 and 47 - else if block) in /node_modules/q/q.js file (see below screenshot). Due to those 2 lines, it was not able to define Q as global variable, as specially when it finds RequireJS. Once commented, it falls into another else if block where it defines Q global variable.

[image: Commented RequireJS else-if block]

Here are couple of articles and different solutions related to this issue:

- [Running Q on page with Require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116780/running-q-on-page-with-require-js)
- [How to load Q library with Require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163145/how-to-load-q-library-with-require-js)